# PHP DOMDocument LoadHTML and setAttribute not working on server

Tags: php

Kind of difficult giving a title to this question.

I am modifying elements and their attributes using the `getElementById` and `setAttribute`.

Here is my code so things are a little easier to understand.

```
$mon_Projet->ID_Projet = mysqli_insert_id($connection);

$result = $mon_Projet->find_Projet($connection);

$t = mysqli_fetch_object($result);

$doc_html = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
@$doc_html->loadHTML($t->Page_Projet);

$doc_html->getElementById('ID_Projet')->setAttribute("value", $t->ID_Projet);
$doc_html->getElementById('your_project_name')->nodeValue = $t->Name_Projet;

$mon_Projet->Page_Projet = $doc_html->saveHTML();

mysqli_free_result($result);

$result = $mon_Projet->Update_Projet($connection);
```

My problem is actually only once uploaded to my server. running this locally is working fine. As you can see I am getting ID_Projet's ID and attributing a new id.

Once running it on the Hosts server, I get this:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in/path_to_file.php on line 35
```

Line 35 is

```
$doc_html->getElementById('ID_Projet')->setAttribute("value", $t->ID_Projet);
```

Why might this run fine locally and not on the server.

Comment: You're suppressing the error on the most important line `@$doc_html->loadHTML($t->Page_Projet);`. Remove the `@` - what does it tell you?

Comment: nothing more. This was just because I had a duplicated ID in my code.

Comment: What does `var_dump($t->Page_Projet)` tell you?

Comment: I am getting all the html I am supposed to find, and the Input with the id 'ID_Projet' is there. What is very frustrating is that all this code is working fine as said on localhost but when running on the server it seems the objects of the DOM are not visible.

Comment: I think that perhaps the version of PHP on your server doesn't have the DOM extension. You may need to install it separately to the base PHP package.

Comment: That is what i thought at first but the php running on the server is PHP Version 5.4.39 and all DOM are activated